# Can't get a function call in a function to work properly

Tags: c, function

I'm writing a program to generate a string of random uppercase letters, then take user input of uppercase letters, along with a character form the user. For any instance of the user input letter in the random string, it replaces that letter with the character entered by the user.

For example, s1 = {BDHFKYL} s2 = {YEIGH} c = '*'

Output = BD*FK*L

The program was working correctly until I added the feature to ask the user to enter what character they would like to replace the letters.

The output is:

```
Please enter at least 2 capital letters and a maximum of 20.
HDJSHDSHDDS
HDJSHDSHDDS
Enter a character to replace occuring letters.
*
NWLRBBMQB
Would you like to enter another string?
```

Here's the code:

```
void fillS1(char x[]);

void fillS2(char x[], char y[], char z);

void strFilter(char a[], char b[], char c);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
 char s1[42];
 char s2[22];
 char x = 0;

 fillS2(s2, s1, x);

 return 0;
}

void fillS1(char x[])
{
 for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
     x[i] = 'A' + random() % 26;
 x[40] = (char)0;
}

void fillS2(char x[], char y[], char z){

 char loopContinue = 0;

 do {

 int i = 0;
 int capitalLetterCheck = 0;

 printf("Please enter at least 2 capital letters and a maximum of 20.\n");
 while (( x[i] = getchar()) != '\n' ) {

    i++;

     }

 x[i] = '\0';

 if (i < 3) {
    printf("You need at least two letters\n");
 }

 else if (i > 21){
    printf("You cannot have more than twenty letters\n");
}


for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if ((x[i] >= 'a') && (x[i] <= 'z')) {
            printf("You many only have capital letters.\n");
            capitalLetterCheck = 2;
        }
    }


if (capitalLetterCheck != 2) {
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if ((x[i] >= 'A') && (x[i] <= 'Z')) {
            puts(x);

            fillS1(y);

            printf("Enter a character to replace occuring letters.\n");
            while ((z = getchar() != '\n')) {

            }

            strFilter(y, x, z);  
            break;
        }
        }
    }

    printf("Would you like to enter another string?\n");
    gets(&loopContinue);

} while (loopContinue != 'n');

}

void strFilter(char a[], char b[], char c){
 int i = 0;
 int n = 0;

 while (n < 20) {

        for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            if (a[i] == b[n]){
                a[i] = c;
            }

    }
    i = 0;
    n++;
}

   puts(a);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's not replacing the characters with a star.

Answer (score 4):

first of all please try to make your code a little easier to read, and I'm not talking about indenting but about its flow.

Also, your example output seems to work fine since there was nothing to change in any string here...?

There are a few things you should keep in mind when coding :

- give your variables and functions explicit names, espcecially if you are going to have someone read your code at some point
- try to keep the flow of your code simple by making small functions when you have a specifig task to execute (get the user's input, generate a random string, etc.) as opposed to just writing most of it in imbricated loops
- You could also have a look at scanf (man scanf) to get the user's input
- Try allocating a buffer when you get the user's input instead of having a static one that may not be of the right size

It's very easy to write some pseudo-code and then translate it into C :

```
WHILE someCondition
    Generate a random string
    Get a string from the user
    Get a character from the user
    Find and replace
END
```

Here is an example of how you could have organised your code (don't use it though - no frees, no getting the user's input, etc.) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* generateString(void)
{
    return "AEIOUYAEIOUY"; // In your implementation, this is where you'd generate the random string
}

char* getStringInput(void)
{
    return "HELLO"; // In your implementation, this is where you'd get the user's string
}

char getCharInput(void)
{
    return '*'; // In your implementation, this is where you'd get the user's character
}

char* findAndReplace(char* randomString, char* userString, char userChar)
{
    int l1;
    int l2;
    int i;
    int j;
    char* output;

    l1 = strlen(randomString);
    l2 = strlen(userString);
    output = (char*)malloc(sizeof(*output) * l1);
    strcpy(output, randomString);
    for (i = 0; i < l1; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < l2; ++j)
            if (randomString[i] == userString[j])
                output[i] = userChar;
    }

    return (output);
}

int main(int ac, char** av)
{
    char* randomString;
    char* userString;
    char userChar;
    char* outputString;

    randomString = generateString();
    userString = getStringInput();
    userChar = getCharInput();
    outputString = findAndReplace(randomString, userString, userChar);
    printf("Result: %s\n", outputString);

    // don't forget to free any allocated buffer

    return (1);
}
```

How much debugging have you done? Try putting some printfs in your code to see what happens - when functions are called, what are your variable's values, etc.
Example :

```
void fillS1(char x[])
{
 printf("-- entering fillS1, buffer value: %s\n", x);
 for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
     x[i] = 'A' + random() % 26;
 x[40] = (char)0;
 printf("-- leaving fillS1, buffer value: %s\n", x);
}
```

(be careful about what's in your buffer before you use printf)

This should tell you pretty quickly what's going wrong.

For example, try checking the value of "c" in strFilter when it's called, and have a second look at how you get the user's input.

Comment: +1 for not directly pointing the bug, and letting the OP do the homework.

Comment: Thank you Damien for a well thought out response. The only reason I made my buffers the values I did is because I'm not allowed to use string handling functions, and the size of s1 needs to be 40 and the maximum size of s2 is 20. I'll do some debugging and see what I find. Again, thank you for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Hey Damien, I've been working on the program and I've worked out most of the bugs but there's one thing I can't figure out. The user input string is doubling itself at the end of the function. Is the because I'm using getchar()? If I had a choice I would rather use getchar() because it makes it easier to check the size of the strings. Thanks for the help.